# Android Emulator shows System UI not responding on boot?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to get a tablet emulator to test the tablet UI for an app I'm writing, but when it boots up the launcher will crash (Pixel Launcher in my case), followed with "System UI has stopped responding".

I've seen some solutions involving decreasing the resolution and memory, but those haven't worked for me. I tried uninstalling all SDK files, images, and Android Studio itself twice but it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Increase the RAM and VM Heap Size of the emulator. Also use the x86 images instead of ARM. Also HAXM can be installed for better performance.

Comment: I'll try increasing those properties. And I do have HAXM installed, and I'm also pretty sure I'm using the x86 images.

Comment: How much of system RAM do you have and what are the VM Heap and RAM you are allocating?

Comment: My computer has 16GB of RAM.The emulator had 1562 MB of RAM, and a 192 MB VM Heap. I made another one with 2024 MB of RAM and 512 MB VM Heap. Now the symptoms have changed, it's just a black screen now. The emulator crashes after a few of minutes.

When I launch it with command line in verbose, the first launch gave a `Permission Denied` error. I tried a fix for that, but now it still crashes without the error. It spams `VCPU shutdown request` in the console.

Comment: This is happening on both emulators, by the way. The one with the original settings and the one with the increased properties.

Comment: I tried a different image and I'm getting it to boot now, but I still have the original "System UI has stopped responding" message, even when I increase the RAM and VM Heap to the values above.

Comment: just out of curiosity... why 2024? & not 2048!!!

Comment: Just try to select another hardware profile. I had a similar error on Pixel and Pixel 2 emulators with Android 8. My quick fix without reconfiguring anything (my only requirement was to test my application on an Android 8): I switched to a Nexus 6 emulator with Android 8 and the error already did not reappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, it seems the issue has been resolved. I updated the Intel HAXM from 6.2.1 to 7.1.0. I also updated my Intel Graphics. I created a Nexus 9 emulator with API 27 and default settings as a control. It's been working with some mild lag for about 10 minutes. So I guess the SDK Manager doesn't install the most recent version of HAXM yet?

Here's the link where I got the installer: [Intel HAXM 7.1.0](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm)